# Recovering a rank-one matrix from its eigendecomposition after randomized rounding

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, algorithms, computer-science, random-matrices

Let $A = xy^T$ be a rank-$1$ matrix, and suppose every entry of $A$ is in $[0,1]$. We can create a binary matrix $A_{\rm rounded}$ by setting 
$$ [A_{\rm rounded}]_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ with probability } A_{ij} \\ 0 & \mbox{ with probability } 1-A_{ij} \end{cases} $$

Is it possible to recover $A$ by looking at the principal eigenvector of $A_{\rm rounded}$? In other words, if $v$ is the principal eigenvector of $A$, can one show that $P(||v./x - {\bf 1}||_2 \geq \epsilon)$ goes to zero for any $\epsilon > 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, where ${\bf 1}$ is the all ones vector and $./$ refers to the elementwise division of two vectors?

I wrote a quick MATLAB simulation that suggests the answer is yes. Here is my code:

> n=20000; %matrix size
>
> %generate matrix;
>
> x = rand(n,1);
>
> y = rand(n,1);
>
> A = x*y';
>
> %generate rounded matrix
>
> B = zeros(n,n);
>
> for i=1:n
>
> ```
> for j =1:n
>
>     if rand>A(i,j)
>
>         B(i,j)=0;
>
>     else
>
>         B(i,j) =1;
>
>     end
>
> end
> ```
>
> end
>
> %eigendecomposition of B
>
> [v,d]=eig(B);
>
> %figure out the index of the principal eigenvector;
>
> m = max(abs(d));
>
> mm = max(m);
>
> i = find(m==mm);
>
> %compare principal eigenvector to true answer
>
> y = v(:,i)./x;
>
> %ideally, y is a multiple of the all-ones vector.
>
> %check how far this is from being the case
>
> J = eye(n,n)-(1/n)*ones(n,n);
>
> norm(J*y)

Running this code with matrix size of 20,000 took me a few hours and returned the following result: if $v$ is the principal eigenvector of $A_{\rm rounded}$, and $v/x$ is the elementwise ratio of $v$ and $x$, then $ ||(I - (1/n) {\bf 1} {\bf 1}^T) v/x||_2 \approx 0.06$. Given that $v$ and $x$ are in $\mathbb{R}^{20,000}$, this strongly suggests the answer is positive. Moreover, in some additional simulations for lower dimensions I seem to be getting that $ ||(I - (1/n) {\bf 1} {\bf 1}^T) v/x||_2 $ generated as above decreases as a function of the dimension of $n$.

Since the answer is likely yes, is this something that is present in the literature? And is there a simple argument to see that recovery is possible, in this or a related model?

Comment: Moved to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/41496/recovering-a-rank-one-matrix-from-its-eigendecomposition-after-randomized-roundi

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question was asked and answered at CSTheory.SE.